# Convert CV template from tex to html using make4ht

Tags: tex4ht, cv, conversion, html, make4ht

I am trying to get a proper `html` version of my cv from the `tex` file. I like to do the conversion as perfectly as possible so that the structure of the `html` can match with the `pdf` properly.

### `cv.tex`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-4pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
  }\vspace{-11pt}
}
\newcommand{\school}[4]{\vspace{1.5mm}
  \textbf{#1} \hfill #2 \textit{#3} \hfill \textit{#4} \vspace{1.5mm}
}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{\Large Name} & \textbf{June, 2021} \\ Address & \textit{\href{mailto:}{Email}}
\end{tabular*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Education}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
       \item[]
            \school
            {University Name}
            {City, Country\\}
            {BSc - Physics}
            {2010 - 2014}
    \end{itemize}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Technical Skills}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
          \begin{itemize}
            \item C++, Python
            \item \LaTeX
          \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

### `cv.pdf` file appears as:

[image]

And I have generated the `cv.html` using the command:

```
make4ht cv.tex
```

### `cv.html` file appears as:

[image]

The conversion is quite okay. But there are some differences in the text-alignment (`City, Country`, `2010-2014` not aligned at right), color of the headings (gray shedcolors not covered fully), `\LaTeX` symbol (appeared simply as `LaTeX`), `item` label (the default label appeared at `University Name` even trough I put `\item[]`).

Is it possible to make the conversion more perfect so that these differences don't appear? And currently, what is the most effective method to convert my above `cv.tex` file to `cv.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need some configurations to change formatting of your HTML file. In particular, `\hfill` and similar commands cannot be supported by TeX4ht. Fortunately, you used custom commands, instead of direct formatting in your document, so it is quite easy to do.

One thing that I would change in your document is that I would use a custom environment instead of `itemize` for the education block. This will enable us to remove the bullet in this case. This is the updated TeX file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-4pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}%
    \begin{shaded}%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}%
    \end{shaded}%
  }\vspace{-11pt}%
}
\newcommand{\school}[4]{\vspace{1.5mm}
  \textbf{#1} \hfill #2 \textit{#3} \hfill \textit{#4} \vspace{1.5mm}
}

% extra environment for education, as you want to get rid of the bullet
\newenvironment{education}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}{\end{itemize}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{\Large Name} & \textbf{June, 2021} \\ Address & \textit{\href{mailto:}{Email}}
\end{tabular*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Education}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{education} 
       \item[]
            \school
            {University Name}
            {City, Country\\}
            {BSc - Physics}
            {2010 - 2014}
\end{education}
          
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Technical Skills}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
          \begin{itemize}
            \item C++, Python
            \item \LaTeX
          \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

You can then use the following `.cfg` file to change the appearance:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,fancylogo}

% handle bullet in education
\ConfigureEnv{education}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="education">}}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
% set padding as you like
\Css{.education ul.itemize1{list-style:none;display:block;padding-left:0em;}}
\Css{.education ul.itemize1 li{display:block;margin:0;padding:0;}}
\Css{.education ul.itemize2 li{list-style:disc outside;display:list-item; }}

% heading boxes
\renewcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="resheading">}%
\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{#1}%
\HCode{</div>}%
}

\catcode`\:=11
% convert shadecolor to CSS
\get:xcolorcss{shadecolor}{\:shadecolor}
\Css{.resheading .colorbox{display:block; width:100\%;padding:3pt;font-size: 1.2em; font-weight:bold; box-sizing:border-box;}}
\Css{.resheading{border: 3px solid \:shadecolor;box-sizing:border-box;padding:1px;background:black;}}
\catcode`\:=12

% handle \school
\renewcommand{\school}[4]{%
\begin{tabular}{l r}%
  \textbf{#1} & #2\\  \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\%
\end{tabular}%
}

% document styling
\Css{body{margin: 1em auto; max-width: 70ch}}

% table styling
\Css{table{width:100\%;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I will describe some important stuff:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,fancylogo}
```

The `fancylogo` option will request text that emulates normal `\LaTeX` logo formatting

```
% handle bullet in education
\ConfigureEnv{education}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="education">}}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
% set padding as you like
\Css{.education ul.itemize1{list-style:none;display:block;padding-left:0em;}}
\Css{.education li{display:block;margin:0;padding:0;}}
```

This code adds `<div class="education">` around the education block. CSS can then be used to remove the bullet. The `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP` code is used to handle paragraphs, it is necessary to use it in order to get valid HTML code.

```
% heading boxes
\renewcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="resheading">}%
\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{#1}%
\HCode{</div>}%
}
\Css{.resheading .colorbox{display:block; width:100\%;padding:3pt;font-size: 1.2em; font-weight:bold; box-sizing:border-box;}}
\Css{.resheading{border: 1px solid black;box-sizing:border-box;}}
```

This handles your `\resheading` command. Most of the original code is not useful in the conversion at all. We just use the `\fcolorbox` to produce box with the grey background. We could use just HTML and CSS for that, but in this way, you can change the color in your document, and it will be changed in HTML as well.

```
% handle \school
\renewcommand{\school}[4]{%
\begin{tabular}{l r}%
  \textbf{#1} & #2\\  \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\%
\end{tabular}%
}
```

I've redefined `\school` to just produce table, as it is an easiest way how to achieve the desired formatting.

The last important things are related to overall look of your document:

```
% document styling
\Css{body{margin: 1em auto; max-width: 70ch}}
```

This sets maximum width of the page and centers it.

```
% table styling
\Css{table{width:100\%;}}
```

This resize tables to use full page width.

Compile using

```
make4ht -c mycfg.cfg cv.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: But your code is not generating the deeper gray color of the outer border of the heading boxes. Can you update to fix it?

Comment: I used `\vspace{1.5mm}` inside the `\school` command for extra vertical space. It appears okay in PDF, but not in HTML. How to solve it?

Comment: Another thing is: When insert an `itemize` environment (`\begin{itemize} \item lipsum
 \end{itemize}`) inside your custom `education` environment to produce a nested list, the `itemize` is not showing the item labels which I want to show.

Comment: @raf I've updated the .cfg file, it should now produce dark gray border around heading boxes, and support nested itemizes inside `\education`.

Comment: Thank you for the update!

Comment: Currently, I am getting the following warnings: `[WARNING] tocid: char-def module not found` and `[WARNING] tocid: cannot fix section id's`. These warnings didn't appear earlier. Why is it happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: @raf do you have full TeX Live installed? one make4ht extension uses ConTeXt's `char-def` library, so you may need to install something like `texlive-context`, if you use for example Linux package manager.

Comment: @raf but this feature is not critical, it just add link destinations to section titles, so you can ignore it

Comment: I am using MiKTeX. And yes, it's not affecting my output file.

Comment: @raf yes, it shouldn't affect it negatively, especially not this file, as it doesn't use LaTeX sections anyway

Comment: one thing I like to know. If I need to insert some equations in the above file and display it properly in HTML, what additional things do I have to be concerned about?

Comment: @raf it is best to use either `make4ht filename.tex "mathml,mathjax"`, or `make4ht filename.tex "mathjax"`. Use both options and you will see which works better for you.

Comment: Thank you, I checked that it serves my purpose even without using `mathml` or `mathjax`. But the appearance gets better by using them.