make4ht: Configure the spacing and alignment in HTML
I like to match the spacing and alignments of texts on HTML output with the PDF output. I am using make4ht version v0.3m (TeX Live 2023/Debian).
My major concern in HTML that I want to fix:

Extra vertical spacing between the lines (especially between Title and Organiser Name)
Month, Year not staying in the same line as Title in Award
The change in label bullet size, its vertical position, and label separation

PDF output

HTML output


TEX file
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    pdftitle={CV}, 
}
\urlstyle{same}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.90} 
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
  }\vspace{-11pt}
}

\newcommand{\workshop}[4]{ 
  \textbf{#1} \\ \textit{#2} \hfill \textit{#3} \\ #4
}

\newcommand{\award}[4]{ 
  \textbf{#1} \hfill \textit{#2} \\ \textit{#3} \\ #4 
}

\newenvironment{myitems}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}{\end{itemize}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\resheading{Workshops}
\begin{myitems}
    \item  
        \workshop
        {Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Title}
        {Organiser Name}
        {Month, Year}
        {Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Description}
\end{myitems}

\resheading{Awards}
\begin{myitems}
    \item
      \award
      {Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Title}
      {Month, Year}
      {Organiser Name}
      {Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Description}
\end{myitems}

\end{document}

CFG file
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/722062/114006

\Preamble{xhtml,fancylogo}

% handle bullet in myitems
\ConfigureEnv{myitems}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="myitems">}}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
% set padding
\Css{.myitems ul.itemize1{list-style:none;display:block;padding-left:1em;}}
\Css{.myitems ul.itemize1 li{display:block;margin:0;padding:0em;}}
\Css{.itemizeHead{float: left; margin-left: -1em; width: 1em;}}
\Css{li.itemize{list-style: none;}}

% heading boxes
\renewcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="resheading">}%
\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{#1}%
\HCode{</div>}%
}

% hyperlink to open sin a new tab % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721744/114006
\Configure{Link}{a}{target="_blank" href=}{id=}{}

\catcode`\:=11
% convert shadecolor to CSS
\get:xcolorcss{shadecolor}{\:shadecolor}
\Css{.resheading .colorbox{display:block; width:100\%;padding:3pt;font-size: 1.2em; font-weight:bold; box-sizing:border-box;}}
\Css{.resheading{border: 3px solid \:shadecolor;box-sizing:border-box;padding:1px;background:black;}}

\ConfigureList{itemize}%
   {\EndP\HCode{<ul \a:LRdir
          class="\getClass{itemize}itemize\expandafter\the
          \csname @itemdepth\endcsname">}%
       \afterGetClass{itemize}%
       \PushMacro\end:itm
\global\let\end:itm=\empty}
   {\PopMacro\end:itm \global\let\end:itm \end:itm
\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi
    \EndP\HCode{</li></ul>}\ShowPar}
   {\end:itm \global\def\end:itm{\EndP\Tg</li>}\HCode{<li class="\getClass{li}itemize">}\par\ShowPar\HCode{<span class="itemizeHead" aria-hidden="true">}\afterGetClass{li}}
   {\HCode{</span>}}

\catcode`\:=12

\renewcommand{\workshop}[4]{%
\begin{tabular}{l r}%
  \multicolumn{2}{p{\linewidth}}{\textbf{#1}} \\  \textit{#2} & \textit{#3} \\ \multicolumn{2}{p{\linewidth}}{{#4}} \\%
\end{tabular}%
}

\renewcommand{\award}[4]{%
\begin{tabular}{l r}%
  \multicolumn{2}{p{\linewidth}}{\textbf{#1} \rightline{\textit{#2}}} \\ \textit{#3} \\ \multicolumn{2}{p{\linewidth}}{{#4}} \\%
\end{tabular}%
}

% document styling
\Css{body{margin: 1em auto; max-width: 85ch}}

% table styling
\Css{table{width:100\%;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble


Try this config file:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/722062/114006

\Preamble{xhtml,fancylogo}

% handle bullet in myitems
\ConfigureEnv{myitems}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="myitems">}}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
% set padding
%\Css{.myitems ul.itemize1{list-style:none;display:block;padding-left:1em;}}
%\Css{.myitems ul.itemize1 li{display:block;margin:0;padding:0em;padding-left: 1rem;}}
%\Css{.itemizeHead{float: left; margin-left: -1em; width: 1em;}}
\Css{.itemizeHead{display: none;}}
%\Css{li.itemize{list-style: none;}}
%
\Css{li.itemize::marker{font-size: 1.3rem; }}
\Css{li.itemize{margin-left: -1.3rem;}}

% heading boxes
\renewcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="resheading">}%
\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{#1}%
\HCode{</div>}%
}

% hyperlink to open sin a new tab % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721744/114006
\Configure{Link}{a}{target="_blank" href=}{id=}{}

\catcode`\:=11
% convert shadecolor to CSS
\get:xcolorcss{shadecolor}{\:shadecolor}
\Css{.resheading .colorbox{display:block; width:100\%;padding:3pt;font-size: 1.2em; font-weight:bold; box-sizing:border-box;}}
\Css{.resheading{border: 3px solid \:shadecolor;box-sizing:border-box;padding:1px;background:black;}}

\ConfigureList{itemize}%
   {\EndP\HCode{<ul \a:LRdir
          class="\getClass{itemize}itemize\expandafter\the
          \csname @itemdepth\endcsname">}%
       \afterGetClass{itemize}%
       \PushMacro\end:itm
\global\let\end:itm=\empty}
   {\PopMacro\end:itm \global\let\end:itm \end:itm
\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi
    \EndP\HCode{</li></ul>}\ShowPar}
   {\end:itm \global\def\end:itm{\EndP\Tg</li>}\HCode{<li class="\getClass{li}itemize">}\par\ShowPar\HCode{<span class="itemizeHead" aria-hidden="true">}\afterGetClass{li}\NoFonts}
   {\EndNoFonts\HCode{</span>}}

\catcode`\:=12

% set itemize dot size
\Css{.itemizeHead{font-size:1.8rem;font-weight: bold; display: block-inline; float: left;}}

\renewcommand{\workshop}[4]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="workshop"><div class="title">}\par\ShowPar%
#1%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HtmlParOff%
\HCode{</div><div class="info"><span class="organiser">}#2\HCode{</span><span class="date">}#3%
\HCode{</span></div><div class="subtitle">}\HtmlParOn\par\ShowPar%
#4
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div></div>}%
}

\renewcommand{\award}[4]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="award"><div class="title">}\par\ShowPar%
#1%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HtmlParOff%
\HCode{</div><div class="info"><span class="organiser">}#3\HCode{</span><span class="date">}#2%
\HCode{</span></div><div class="subtitle">}\HtmlParOn\par\ShowPar%
#4
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div></div>}
}

\Css{.workshop .title, .award .title{font-weight: bold;}}
\Css{.workshop .info, .award .info{display: grid; grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr; font-style: italic;}}
\Css{.info .date{text-align: right;}}

% document styling
\Css{body{margin: 1em auto; max-width: 85ch}}

% table styling
\Css{table{width:100\%;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble


It produces this:

It is not the same layout as in PDF, but that is because it would be difficult to put the date in awards on the same line as the title and align it to the right. CSS and LaTeX work differently in this regard. So, I put the organizer's name and date on the same line in both cases. This is the changed code:
\renewcommand{\workshop}[4]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="workshop"><div class="title">}\par\ShowPar%
#1%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HtmlParOff%
\HCode{</div><div class="info"><span class="organiser">}#2\HCode{</span><span class="date">}#3%
\HCode{</span></div><div class="subtitle">}\HtmlParOn\par\ShowPar%
#4
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div></div>}%
}

\renewcommand{\award}[4]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="award"><div class="title">}\par\ShowPar%
#1%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HtmlParOff%
\HCode{</div><div class="info"><span class="organiser">}#3\HCode{</span><span class="date">}#2%
\HCode{</span></div><div class="subtitle">}\HtmlParOn\par\ShowPar%
#4
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div></div>}
}

\Css{.workshop .title, .award .title{font-weight: bold;}}
\Css{.workshop .info, .award .info{display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; font-style: italic;}}
\Css{.info .date{text-align: right;}}

In the previous version, we used tables, so it was more challenging to position things precisely. This version uses HTML elements and CSS, so it is more flexible.

Thanks. As u know we used tables earlier and I got the desired output with tables in the other sections, as discussed in an earlier question. So, I am thinking of keeping the tables for those sections and only using this HTML element on the workshop, award etc. But I just noticed the bullet label separation is appearing bigger in the table element than in this HTML element, the latter one is preferred. What is controlling the separation difference in the config?

Also, if the organizer name is a bit longer, it gets warped before it is needed with this config and makes it look different than the PDF. For example, you can use Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Organiser Name. How can I control the warp here?

And, I wish to shift the bullet labels a little bit more to the right to appear as same as the pdf, like aligned with the border of the shaded heading.

@raf see the update, it should work better

Thanks, but increasing the font size of itemized labels is causing displacement from the lines. How to fix it? See the screenshot: https://i.sstatic.net/UmOjnXRE.png.
Also, as I mentioned, the label separation appears bigger for the tabular env, like for comparison, I have kept \workshop as tabular env and \award with your suggested HTML elements. Would it be possible to make the label separation the same smaller for both cases?

@raf these may need some more advanced CSS hacks. I can try it next week

Thank you. Take your time.

@raf I've added another version. It uses the default itemize bullet, but it seems to work better in keeping the bullet in place

Thank you. However, the issue I expressed in the previous comment is not being resolved.

Also, using the default is changing my desired bullet style on the nested lists. I might need to update the MWE to better understand the situation, or add another question.

@raf yes probably another question. but I think the solution is to just have smaller bullets. It would fix all the positioning issues.

I see, I will be okay with a smaller bullet size. But I got the same issue of the bullet label separation difference between tabular env end HTML elements, as mentioned in previous comment.

@raf I think it would be better to use HTML elements instead of tabular in all cases, to keep things consistent

I get your point. But TBH with you, I'm a bit hesitant to shift all other commands explicitly to HTML elements bcz I am more comfortable with LaTeX commands.
